# select fields from two level parent model in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Assuming I have 3 models named `Content`, `Category`, `Zone`. `Content` is child of `Category` model, `Category` is child of `Zone` model. Hierarchical structure look like this

```
Zone
---Category
------Content
```

Now I want to get data from Content table with some fields of parent model. I can get data from immediate parent but can't select from parents parent model

what I tried?
here is the query I tried

```
$result = $this->Content->find('all', array('recursive' => 2, 'contain' => array('Category.Zone'), 'fields' => 'Content.name, Category.name, Category.Zone.name')); //problem is Category.Zone.name otherwise all is ok
```

This query can select data from `Content` and its parent `Category` but cant get data form `Zone` model which is parents of `Category` model.

**N.B.** I can do this by joining. But I want to do this by association.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Recursive will be ignored as soon you use `Containable Behavior` see [Docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containablebehavior-options)

```
$result = $this->Content->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Category' => array('Zone')
    ), 
    'fields' => 'Content.name, Category.name, Zone.name'
));
```

You have passed `'contain' => array('Category.Zone')`, Model should have their on keys, and optionally you can set association in place of values. like :-

```
'contain' => array(
    'Category' => array(/*conditions*/),
    'Zone' => array(/*conditions*/)
),
```

I am assuming you had already did associations in models, so no need to pass here.

Comment: Zone is not associated with Content. Zone associated with Category and Category associated with Content. Now I want select field form Zone model.

Comment: I try with your code. but its not work.

`$result = $this->Content->find('all', array( 'contain' => array('Category' => array('Zone')), 'fields' => 'Content.name, Category.name, Zone.name'));`

Comment: have you put associations in respective models ? if not pass conditions in containable

Comment: Yes I put association in respective models

Comment: Okay, can you please, remove the `fields` node from array, let it fetch all, and see what output comes

Comment: additionally you can refer to, CakePHP docs for [Deeper Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containing-deeper-associations) using containable, but this is how it works!

Comment: I solve the problem. I specified field name in contains array

Comment: @Md.SahadatHossain. can you please post your solution as an answer here.